# Moving from Amazon Linun to ubuntu, now my init script isn't working.

Tags: bash, services, init.d

We are in the testing phase of moving from amazon linux to ubuntu for some of our servers.  We have a mono app that is run as a service and on the amazon linux box it ran fine.  I know that some things are different with services between the 2 OSs. For instance on Amazon Linux the source function library is in a different location.

I did not write this app or the init script, its just my job to get it working now.
Can you help me get this script running smoothly?
Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/wowza2s3

#source function library for Amazon Linux 
#. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions 

#source function library for Ubuntu
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

RETVAL=0
prog=wowza2s3
lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

MONO=/usr/bin/mono
EXE=/usr/local/WOWZAtoS3/WOWZAtoS3.exe
PID_FILE=/var/run/wowza2s3.pid

start()
{
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    (exec $MONO $EXE & echo $! >> "$PID_FILE") && success || failure
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
        echo
        return $RETVAL
}
stop()
{
        if [ ! -f "$PID_FILE" ]; then
                action $"Stopping $prog: " /bin/true
                return 0
        fi
        PID=`cat "$PID_FILE"`
        if [ -n "$PID" ]; then
                /bin/kill "$PID" >/dev/null 2>&1
                RETVAL=$?
                if [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ]; then
                        RETVAL=1
                        action $"Stopping $prog: " /bin/false
                else
                        action $"Stopping $prog: " /bin/true
                fi
        else
                 # failed to read pidfile
                action $"Stopping $prog: " /bin/false
                RETVAL=4
        fi

        if [ "x$runlevel" = x0 -o "x$runlevel" = x6 ] ; then
            trap '' TERM
            killall $prog 2>/dev/null
            trap TERM
        fi
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
        rm -f "$PID_FILE"
        return $RETVAL
}
restart() {
    stop
    start
}
force_reload() {
    restart
}

rh_status() {
        status -p $PID_FILE mono
}

rh_status_q() {
        rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}


case "$1" in
        start)
                rh_status_q && exit 0
                start
                ;;
        stop)
                if ! rh_status_q; then
                        rm -f $lockfile
                        exit 0
                fi
                stop
                ;;
        restart)
                restart
                ;;
    force_reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
esac
exit $RETVAL
```

currently when I run 
`service wowza2s3 start` it returns

```
root@ip-10-0-1-10:~# service wowza2s3 start
Starting wowza2s3: /etc/init.d/wowza2s3: line 20: success: command not found
/etc/init.d/wowza2s3: line 20: failure: command not found
```

although it does start the app and it works as intended.

`service wowza2s3 stop` does not return anything and doesn't stop the process

`service wowza2s3 status` returns

```
root@ip-10-0-1-10:~# service wowza2s3 status
status: invalid option: -p
Try `status --help' for more information.
```

Thanks

Comment: The `status` command is a link to `initctl`. I don't have access to an amazon Linux installation so I can't check what the `-p` option does on their version of `initctl`. Can you check and let us know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was rewriting this script using the upstart system.

Following a guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/)

Here is my code.  Very straight forward for me to understand.

```
description "Wowza to S3 service: copies videos to S3 and updating SQL DB records accordingly. WOWZAtoS3 is written in mono by DevUserName"
author "Greyhammer"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown


script

    export MONO="/usr/bin/mono"
    export EXE="/usr/local/WOWZAtoS3/WOWZAtoS3.exe"
    echo $$ > /var/run/wowza2s3.pid
    exec $MONO $EXE

end script

pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] WOWZAtoS3 Starting" >> /var/log/wowza2s3.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/wowza2s3.pid
    echo "[`date`] WOWZAtoS3 Stopping" >> /var/log/wowza2s3.log
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention three errors. The first two are simple enough:

```
Starting wowza2s3: /etc/init.d/wowza2s3: line 20: success: command not found
/etc/init.d/wowza2s3: line 20: failure: command not found
```

The `success` and `failure` commands are not standard. They are, presumably, some sort of Amazon Linux specific thing. However, based on the context, I can make an educated guess about what they're supposed to do:

```
(exec $MONO $EXE & echo $! >> "$PID_FILE") && success || failure
```

That means "run a command and then run `success` if it worked and `failure` if it didn't. I have no idea why anyone would choose such a convoluted way of writing that. As far as I can tell, that line is equivalent to:

```
(exec $MONO $EXE & echo $! >> "$PID_FILE")
```

Presumably, the `success` and `failure` programs simply return a `0` (success) and non-`0` (`failure`) exit value. The shell does that anyway though, which is why the line above should be the same. Whatever. If you really need to call an external program for this, use the shell builtins `true` and `false`:

```
(exec $MONO $EXE & echo $! >> "$PID_FILE") && true || false
```

The next error is harder to understand. The `status` program is just a symlink to `/sbin/initctl`. The version of `initctl` on Ubuntu doesn't have a `-p` option. I haven't been able to find the manual of whatever `initctl` is used on Amazon Linux. Presumably, if you can find it, you can check what the `-p` option does and figure out the equivalent in Ubuntu's `initctl`.

Comment: What about why the stop doesn't stop the service? Is it because the start doesn't create a pid file?

Comment: @Greyhammer no, that's because the `-p` option for `status` doesn't exist, so the `if ! rh_status_q; then rm -f $lockfile; exit 0` is executed, so the script exits before the `stop` function is run.

Comment: So i logged into an AWS Linux box and found that service doesn't have a -p  http://pastebin.com/raw/KzMHwGua

Comment: @Greyhammer not `service`, it's your `initctl` that has it (`status` is a link to `initctl`).

Comment: my mistake, i typoed, the first pastbin is from initctl  here is status http://pastebin.com/raw/4ymjxZAU

Comment: @Greyhammer then you'll have to ask whoever wrote the script what that is supposed to do.

Comment: @tendon, unfortunately, that person hasn't worked here in years. The company has had the "if it ain't broke, don't touch it" attitude.  Now im dealing with the fall out.

Comment: @tendon, can you point me in the direction of some good documentation on how to build a new init script?  all I need it to do is start, stop, status.   I believe once I get the init script working, all I would have to do to get it to startup at system boot is `ln -s /etc/init.d/wowza2s3 /etc/rc3.d/S85wowza2s3` correct?

Comment: @Greyhammer not off the top of my head, no. I would just search Google. My answer already shows you how to fix at least most of your issues. You don't seem to have tried any of my suggestions.

Comment: @tendon, You mistook my comment, I have tried what you suggested, and start seems to work and creates a pid lock file and starts the service.  But because I can't seem to find what `status -p` should be doing, stop and status still don't work. So I figured it would be easier to start fresh and create my own script so that I would know exactly what it was doing and why.  I did not mean to offend you my friend.  Thank you for your help thus far.